# PubNub: Cannot resolve method subscribe

Tags: android, pubnub

I am new to android programming and I am using PubNub for the first time. 
I have included the .jar file in lib. I have also imported it.

I am following the steps given here - 
http://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-java-sdk#copy_and_paste_examples

but I am getting this error message. -
" Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(java.lang.String,anonymous javax.security.auth.callback.Callback)'

I am using Android Studio. Also, I am putting my entire code in mainActivity. I am not sure where exactly the code for pubnub goes.

My Main Activity -

```
 package com.example....<hidden>;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.pubnub.api.Pubnub;
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubError;
import com.pubnub.api.PubnubException;
import com.pubnub.api.*;
  import org.json.*;

  import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;

  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private TextView testing;
Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("<mypubkey>", "<mysubkey>");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    /* Subscribe to the demo_tutorial channel */
    try {
        pubnub.subscribe("demo_tutorial", new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }

            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                System.out.println(error.getErrorString());
            }
        });
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My gradle -

```
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Pubnub-*.jar')
}
```

Please let me know how to use pubnub if I am completely doing this wrong.. i.e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
```

There is your issue. Pubnub uses its own callback. The rest of your code looks good, but the reason it says it cannot be resolved is because there is no implementation of subscribe that takes in a `String` and a `javax.security.auth.callback.Callback`.

Delete that import from your code and everything should work since you have included `com.pubnub.api.*`. If you would like to explicitly include it, the import statement is as follows:

```
import com.pubnub.api.Callback;
```

One other error that caused me a lot of trouble when I was starting with PubNub on android is forgetting to request proper internet permissions. Be sure the following lines are in your manifest after the `<manifest>` tag and before the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Also, I believe your gradle import should be ok if Android studio recognizes the functions. To make things easier in the future, feel free to include PubNub's hosted library by using the following dependency.

```
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.7.2'
```

Best of luck, let me know if you have any further questions!